# "I am him" vs "I am he"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, personal-pronouns

A: "Cablegram for Mr.Smith"

B: "I am him."

B: "I mean, I am *he*."

Why the correction? What difference does it make?

Similarly: "I am not her" / "I am not she"?

Comment: "Cablegram for Mr. Smith" is not a phrase used in Modern English. You must be reading British novels from the early 20th century. Many of the characters in these novels talk like upper-class twits, including goofy sentences like "It is I".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Him* and *her* are the objective case forms of the pronouns *he* and *she*, respectively. The objective case is used nearly exclusively for direct and indirect objects, objects of prepositions, and objective complements. In the sentence *I am him*, the pronoun is functioning as a predicate nominative, so it must be in the nominative case; hence, it takes its nominative form, *he*.

Comment: Now suppose I were a grammar book, this is how I would answer. Can I bother you for a dumbed-down version for people like me who haven't learned these fancy definitions by heart? =)

Comment: Sure! In short, the subject of a sentence, the one performing the action, is in the nominative case, which is the same as its objective case for all nouns. For some pronouns, however, the forms for the two cases are different (in this case, *he* is nominative and *him* is objective). Additionally, the "objects" (they're properly called predicate nominatives) of any verbs that deal with the subject's state of being (these are linking verbs; examples include to be, to seem, to look [adjective]) will be in the nominative case as well.

Comment: Looking at the sentence *I am him*, we see that *him* is the "object" of a form of *to be*, *am* in this situation; therefore, it is a predicate nominative and must take its nominative form *he* instead of the objective *him*.